# Practically Calculating Cramer-Rao Lower Bound

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, signal-detection

What is the method to compute Cramer-Rao lower bound for a particular application. For example I have an application in which FFT of an incoming signal is performed to get a Coarse estimate and then Interpolation between bins of interest is performed to get a finer frequency estimate. Now how can I compare my results with a Cramer-Rao lower bound?